# Inequality about i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability, inequality

**Problem**

If $X$ and $ Y$ are i.i.d random variables, then we have

$$E[|X+Y|]\ge E[|X|]$$.

I have an approach for it a long time ago, by assuming there is a density function for it, and recently I revisited this problem.

I wonder if there is an explicit way(some simple and easy way) to explain this inequality, because the inequality looks simple.

And I do not know if this problem is duplicate. If it is not, I hope someone can give the inequality an explanation.

Thanks.

---

If needed, [this](http://zym8903.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/expectation.pdf) is the proof by using density function.

Comment: Sorry, I did the wrong calculation. Forget about it...

Answer (score 2):

Fix $x$ and consider the function $c_x:y\mapsto |x+y|$. Since $c_x$ is convex, Jensen inequality yields
$$
|x+\mathbb E(Y)|=c_x(\mathbb E(Y))\leqslant\mathbb E(c_x(Y))=\mathbb E(|x+Y|).
$$
If $X$ is independent of $Y$, integrating both sides with respect to the distribution of $X$ yields
$$
\mathbb E(|X+\mathbb E(Y)|)\leqslant\mathbb E(|X+Y|).
$$
If furthermore $\mathbb E(Y)=0$, this is the inequality in the OP.

Finally, some hypothesis which guarantees the result is that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and integrable and that $\mathbb E(Y)=0$.

Comment: I do not understand why $X=1,Y=1$ doesn't satisfy the inequality. And the OP has said i.i.d r.v. and we assume that expectation exists.

Comment: Sorry, I was too hasty. Cancelling this indication.